# SwipeCellKit crash when try to delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Hello I am using [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) for my `UITableView`. I want to do the deletion when swipe the cell. This is how I handle the delete part. `self.deleteLeave()` is calling to web service and delete the selected leave entry in the server side. Then if its successfully deleted in the server side I want to delete that object from the current array and update my `UITableView`. But my problem is when I swipe and click on the delete button or else dragged it for some extent app is crashing by giving an exception.

**Error**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion
        self.com.showProgress()
        let dict=self.arrayPendings[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
        if let reid=dict["RequestId"] as? Int
        {
            self.selectedReqID=String(reid)
        }
        self.deleteLeave(){ (status) in

            if(status)
            {

                let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in

                    self.com.removeProgress()
                     self.arrayPendings.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                   self.tblPendingLeaves.beginUpdates()
                    //self.tblPendingLeaves.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
                    self.tblPendingLeaves.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                    action.fulfill(with: .delete)
                    self.tblPendingLeaves.endUpdates()
                }




            }
        }

    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "Delete")

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
When i call delete it crash and show me the same error.

What i dis is:
delete data from tableView then delete the same data from myDataSource(for example: remove data from array). This will handle your case but it will not refresh the table. (If you close and reopen the project it will delete it from table view).

So check the connections between your data and your table.